# Proof that $\oint_r d(x,N + n) < 0 $?

Tags: inequality, optimization, taylor-expansion, contour-integration

Let $f(x)$ be a real-entire function such that for all $x>0$ we have $\DeclareMathOperator{\dmu}{d\!}$,

- $f(x) > 0$, $f'(x) > 0$ , $f '' (x) > 0$,
- and also $0 < D^M f(0) < D^{M-1} f(0)$,

Furthermore, put $g(x,n) = \frac{f(x)}{x^n}$ where $n$ is a positive integre and for $0<T<1$ let

- $x_0(n)$ be a real satisfying $x_0 (n)> 0$ and such that
  $$
  g ' (x_0(n),n) = 0,
  $$
- $r(n)$ be a contour that contains the real interval $[T,x_0(n) + T]$ but not $0$ , not a negative number and no poles or zero's off the real line.

> **Conjecture A:** there is Always an integer $N$ ( depending on $f$ ) such that for all $n > N$
> $$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} \bigg[(x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T) - \sqrt n \ln(e+n)  g(x,n) \frac{g '' (x,n) }{g ' (x,n) }\bigg]\dmu x < 0. $$

A similar conjecture that is probably not compatibel with Conjecture A (they probably cannot both be true , but I believe at least one is true).

> **Conjecture B:** there is Always an integer $N$ ( depending on $f$ ) such that for all $n > N$ there exists a positive $w$ independent of $n$ such that
> $$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} \bigg[(x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T) -  \frac{w g(x,n) g '' (x,n) \sqrt { f '' (x)} }{g ' (x,n) }\bigg]\dmu x < 0. $$

( the derivatives are with respect to $x$ , not $n$ )

How to prove/disprove them ?

In case these contour integrals look random/confusing notice that

$$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} (x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T)\dmu x $$

is just the sequence of Taylor coëfficiënts for $f(x)$.
Also
$$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)}  g(x,n) \frac{g '' (x,n) }{g ' (x,n) }\dmu x$$

is simply minimum( $f(x)/x^n $) for $x > 1.$
So basically we want to understand how good the intuïtive estimate min( $f(x)/x^n $)  is compared to $D^n f(x) / n! $.

**EDIT**
Maybe this helps ??

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiman-Valiron_theory

Comment: I added conjecture B.

Comment: EDIT

Maybe this helps ??

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiman-Valiron_theory

Comment: What is the motivation for the $\ln(e+n)$ term? It seems quite unnatural in the context of the integral.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It is to be considered as a term smaller than a power so that the equation is still valid. A function smaller than a power ... log is a natural choice.

Comment: See also an "application " or related topic : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714585/o-exp-lnx-ln-lnx2-sum-n-0-infty-a-n-xn-and-0-a-n-asym